# How to create custom fields when responding to a GET request in express?

Tags: javascript, json, express, http, get

This is a fairly straightforward problem. When my express GET method processes the request, if it encounters an error I want to send a status code of 500 and a response with the fields:

```
{
  "message": "Not found",
  "internal_code": "Invalid parameters"
}
```

Now in my code I am using:

```
res.status(500).json({
   message: "Not found",
   internal_code: "Invalid parameters"
})
```

And when I receive the response I get:

```
response: {
   status: 500
   data: { message: 'Not found', internal_code: 'Invalid parameters' }
}
```

Now, instead of the 'message' and 'internal_code' being in the data field, I want them to be fields of their own. Is this possible?

Comment: How the 'response' is structured depends on your HTTP client. You can easily modify it though by creating a small function that takes properies from `data` to its parent.

Comment: If you have only one thing, you can send text back using .send("someTxt"). I am not sure why you would need separate fields(you can still access it by adding the body), but having separate fields would mean that the status is part of the data object, which would be very confusing practice to abide by.